# Spring MVC - private field on entity not populated from POST

Tags: java, spring-mvc, post, binding, request

I have a private field `name` on an `Entity` class: `Product`, which doesn't have a `setName()` method due to the business logic not allowing names to be changed.

I have an endpoint of the form:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint", method = POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public Product saveProduct(
            @Validated(FormSubmission.class) Product product,
            Errors errors,
            @RequestParam("sellerId") long sellerId) { ... }
```

I was under the impression that Spring was able to populate private fields as well when parsing request bodies but the `name` property stays `null` after a correctly formatted POST request unless I add a `setName()` method to `Product`.

Is the setter a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

[The private modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed in its own class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

and if you are outside, you can't read/write.

Comment: Spring uses reflection and is able to autowire private fields with beans just fine

Comment: Spring is using Jackson to deserialize your object and I'm not sure if setAccessible(true) is used by default. If your property is null without setter then you probably can't access to change the value.

Comment: Isn't Jackson used for JSON?

Comment: You're right and when you call your controller's method, you are passing JSON that is deserialized into, in this case, Product.

Comment: I'm not passing JSON which is why I asked, my code snippet clearly states that my action consumes x-www-urlencoded data